# Chrome Android - Inconsistent oAuth Behaviour incognito vs regular

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, oauth, instagram-api

This questions is related to this other one I posted a few days ago:
[Instagram oAuth Authentication postMessage issue only with Mobile Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45616740/instagram-oauth-authentication-postmessage-issue-only-with-mobile-browsers)

Pretty much the issue I have is that when logging in my app with Instagram Chrome will behave inconsistently (on Android) and cause me some problems.

As I say in that other thread, IG authentication will reply with the required token and data to authenticate the user in my app.
It will do this by replying with a script that sends that data back to the original window, using `window.opener.postMessage()`.

When I run my app on Chrome in Incognito mode, `window.opener.postMessage` will work without any issue since only one tab is opened and the reference to the `opener` isn't lost.

However, when I run this on the same browser but in regular mode (like probably 90% of people will) the behaviour is different.
Chrome will open a tab, close it and open a new one to input auth data. However, `window.opener` here won't work because the `opener` reference has been lost (is now `null`).

How come the same browser, on the same device will have such a different behaviour between two modes?
Does anybody know why this happens and how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Hey, did you ever solve this issue or find a workaround ? Currently experiencing something similar at the moment.